# I reached a contradiction while proving pythagorean theorem, but I don't know what I did wrong?

Tags: proof-verification

[image]

By relocating the two triangles in the bottom to the top, I created the rectangle with sides $a$ and $b+b=2b$. Then, doesn't this imply that $c^2=2ab$? I am thinking that the area of four triangles add up to $c^2$ and using this fact to prove the pythagorean theorem. I know $c^2=a^2+b^2$, but this makes perfect sense to me.

Comment: Area of your paralellogram is $c^2\sin2A$.

Comment: The upper figure is a square only when a=b.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quadrilateral at the top is not a square, so its area is not $c^2$.